# Is it possible to run code from a downloaded framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, bundle

I want to present a ViewController from a framework which is downloaded later in the app document directory (Something like Microsoft Code-Push in React Native).
Be more specific: I want to install an app (in React Native, Swift, etc) then it would download another swift(objc) compiled app and run it in the next startup.
(I don't care about the first app but It's critical to run a swift compiled code.)

Comment: See the first Q&A in this document: https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/faq/index.html

Comment: @Omnia If your question is specific to React-Native or any Javascript based framework, then I can Post my answer. Please elaborate a bit more

Comment: For "swift compiled code" (or any compiled code), the answer is no. For something based on JavaScript or other runtime-interpreted language, see the above comments.

Comment: @DonMag I've read this document before. It's not the case. I want to download and run a pre-compiled binary code not JS code.

Comment: @Shubham I've changed my question to be more specific. I don't care about the first app. I just want to download and replace somehow the first app with the second app. so in next run I will see the downloaded app.

Comment: @Omnia - as you see, the answer is No, you cannot do that.

Comment: @DonMag But I've seen some app that they download a bundle (including .Storyboardc, .nib, .png, GoogleMap.bundle, .otf font) and use them in the app in their next run. How is it possible?

Comment: @Omnia - you can download resources... you cannot download *compiled executable code*.

Comment: @Omnia - everything you are describing makes it sound like you are trying to do something underhanded.... trying to get around Apple's review process... trying to install malware / trojans / viruses... trying to install code to hack the phones... trick people into giving away their money... etc.

Comment: @DonMag Yes. Exactly! I want to get around Apple's review process but I'm not trying to do any sabotage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have now learned in the comments, you cannot download and "run-on-the-fly" compiled code.

A couple thoughts though...

As you are trying to *"get around Apple's review process"* you should be aware that any method you use to change your app after approval can be risky.

Whether it's downloading graphics, updated data files, config files to change appearance or functionality, using Cordova or React Native (as with Code-Push), etc - minor changes are fine.

Data updates, new imagery, etc. Even layout changes handled by your internal code are no big deal.

However, making major changes, particularly when it is obviously done to get around initial rejection, will end up resulting in your account being banned if/when you get caught.